# M.2-SSD versus NVMe M.2: What is the difference?

Tags: ssd

It appears the connector is almost identical (frustratingly almost identical).

What is the difference between these two animals?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about SATA over M.2 vs. NVMe over M.2. Both of these are for SSDs.

M.2 standard specifies the physical connector and how it can be wired. It allows for a few configurations, each of them possibly providing more than one interface. In particular, M.2 can provide SATA interface (electrically compatible with the traditional SATA connector) and/or PCI-e interface (electrically compatible with the traditional PCI-e connector). NVMe is a protocol for connecting storage over PCI-e.

SATA III supports up to 6 Gbps transfers. A single PCI-e v3 lane is up to 1 GB/s (= 8 Gbps). M.2 provides up to four PCI-e lanes, that's 4 GB/s combined (or 8 GB/s with PCI-e v4).

So NVMe *can* run faster than SATA. It's also more optimized for flash drives like SSDs. It doesn't mean it always *does* run faster than SATA - there are NVMe disks that are slow enough that they could run over SATA as well if they were equipped with a SATA electrical connection.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it an NVMe M.2 device will almost, but not quite, fit in an M.2 SATA slot?  The slots seem very similar?

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica What type(s) a M.2 slot supports is encoded in it's connector: https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln301626/how-to-distinguish-the-differences-between-m-2-cards?lang=en

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica Because the physical form factor of the connector is specified by M.2 standard, so if both are M.2 then they will be similar. Similar - not idential - because M.2 specifies a bunch of different electrical interface configurations with incompatible pin assignments, and to prevent insertion of incompatible devices a system of keyed notches was employed. Position of the notch determines how pins in the connector are wired and a device won't physically fit if it's electrically incompatible with the configuration of pins used in that particular M.2 slot.

Comment: @gronostaj  Yes. What is confusing is that the plain M.2 is _almost_ the same connector as NVMe M.2... like to within 0.5mm. They should have really keyed it differently!

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica You're looking at one of them upside down. With drives oriented properly the keys are on opposite sides of the connector.